# Having trouble inserting backslashes into a string

Tags: regex, perl

For example, I have a line like this:

```
abc prt[67][2]
```

I need to insert backslashes into this line in this way:

```
abc prt\[67\]\[2\]
```

So basically, whenever `[somenumber]` occurs in the lines of the file, I need to convert it to `\[somenumber\]`

Have tried this, but I'm sure its wrong because it's not working.

```
$line =~ s{[(\d+)}{\\[$1]}g;
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You also asked this in /r/perl, which is fine, but it's a courtesy to let people know there might already be answers elsewhere: https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/rhrf3s/having_trouble_in_matching_replacing/

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the 1st bracket and include the 2nd bracket in the pattern side of the substitution:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ s{\[(\d+)]}{\\[$1\\]}g;
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
abc prt[67][2]
foo[0]
```

Prints:

```
abc prt\[67\]\[2\]
foo\[0\]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match

```
(?<!\\)\[\d+(?=])
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\\)` Negative lookbehind, assert not already a `\` directlyt to the left
- `\[` Match `[`
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=])` Postive lookahead, assert `]` directly to the right

And replace with the full match between backslashes.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3NhErl/1)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = 'abc prt[67][2]';
$line =~ s/(?<!\\)\[\d+(?=])/\\$&\\/g;
print $line
```

Output

```
abc prt\[67\]\[2\]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
echo 'abc prt[67][2] [no number]' | perl -lpE 's/(\[)(\d+)(\])/\\\1\2\\\3/g'
abc prt\[67\]\[2\] [no number]
```

Just don't get lost in all the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

A few additions are needed:

```perl
$line =~ s{\[(\d+)\]}{\\[$1\\]}g;
#          ^      ^^       ^^
```

Notably, `[` and `]` need to be escaped in the pattern because they have a special meaning otherwise.

---

You asked to escape the `[` and `]` that enclose "numbers".

Have you considered escaping all `[` and `]`?

```perl
$line =~ s{([\[\]])}{\\$1}g;
```

Have you considered escaping all non-word characters?

```perl
$line =~ s{(\W)}{\\$1}g;
```

or

```perl
$line = quotemeta($line);
```